# Show all content related to child taxonomy terms in parent

Tags: taxonomy-terms

I don't think I could explain it any better here then I have in the title.

Basically if I have a taxonomy term call `Parent` and it has sub terms called `Child 1` and `Child 2`. I'd like to be able to see any content related to `Parent`'s sub terms (`Child 1` & `Child 2`) appear on the `Parent` taxonomy page.

Thanks in advanced!

Comment: Hey, just to clarify a thing or two: So you're just trying to do this with a view block showing on the parent page? And when you say that you want to see 'content related' to the child terms, do you actually mean you are trying to see their fields or are you talking about something else?

Comment: A view block would be the preferred option. The 'related content' are the nodes that have been assigned to the taxonomy using the taxonomy reference field when creating content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking around I have found the solution that helps me. It's a module called [Hierarchical Select](http://drupal.org/project/hierarchical_select).

Answer (score -1):

Use [Hierarchical Select](https://drupal.org/project/hierarchical_select) module and in manage display filed setting for that.

> This module defines the "hierarchical_select" form element, which is a
>   greatly enhanced way for letting the user select items in a hierarchy.